# Prove this inequality using inner product definition.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that

$(x_1 + \dots + x_n)^2 \leq n({x_1}^2 + \dots + {x_n}^2)$

for all positive integers n and all real numbers $x_1, \dots x_n.$

What I tried:

Taking the square root of both sides you get

$(x_1 + \dots + x_n)\leq \sqrt{n({x_1}^2 + \dots + {x_n}^2)} = \sqrt{n}||x||$

$\frac{(x_1 + \dots + x_n)}{\sqrt{n}}\leq ||x||$

Which basically says that the sum of the elements of the some x divided by the root of the number of elements is less than equal to the length of x, where $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$.

This last part makes intuitive sense to me I just don't know how to prove it. I tried using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality earlier but that wasn't working either. Help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that by Cauchy Schwarz we have:

$$x_{1}+...+x_{n}=\pmatrix{x_{1}\\x_{2}\\.\\.\\.\\x_{n}}\cdot\pmatrix{1\\1\\.\\.\\.\\1\\}\le\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}1}=\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert\sqrt{n}$$

Comment: oh my god that was so sneaky thank you I wouldnt have thought of that on my own!

Comment: Glad you learned a new trick. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer relying on the [rearrangement inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality): Without loss of generality, we can assume $x_1\leq\ldots\leq x_n$. Let
$$
\sigma_j(i)=\begin{cases}i+j &i+j\leq n\\ i+j-n&i+j>n\end{cases}.
$$
Then one checks that
$$
(\sum_i x_i)^2=\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j=\sum_j\sum_i x_i x_{\sigma_j(i)}.
$$
Intuitively, in the $n\times n$ matrix $(x_ix_j)$, we are summing along the diagonals instead of along rows and coloumns. Invoking the rearrangement inequality
$$
\sum_i x_i x_{n-i+1}\leq \sum_i x_i x_{\sigma_j(i)} \leq \sum_i x_i^2,
$$
we obtain
$$
n(x_1x_n+x_2x_{n-1}+\ldots+x_nx_1)\leq(x_1+\ldots+x_n)^2\leq n(x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2).
$$